# Matrix Calculus example

Tags: calculus, matrices

How do I use chain rule to calculate the derivative of $ h(\textbf{x})  $, where $ h(\textbf{x}) = f(\textbf{Sx}), f:R^n   \to R$ and $ \textbf{S}$ is a matrix.

I know how to use chain rule to compute derivative of single variable functions, and I know basic operations on matrix and vectors. But I'm not sure how to use chain rule on matrix functions. Any reference will be appreciated.

Comment: What is $\mathbf{Sy}$?

Comment: Seems to be a matrix-vector product...

Comment: Your lecture / text / notes *should* have a multivariable form of the chain rule, like $$\frac{d f}{d t}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t}.$$

Comment: OK, so changing $\mathbf{y}$ to $\mathbf{x}$ didn't really clarify anything, but I'll go with J. M.'s assumption. Here you go: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative and also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient. That has all you need (I presume you are really asking about what is explained in the second link).